# roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch error with ros indigo version and Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS on Jetson tk1 board

Tags: ros, openni-launch, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any one can help me..When this run I got following output...I used ros indigo version and Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with Jetson tk1 board...

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [2552]
process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [2553]
process[camera/rgb_debayer-3]: started with pid [2554]
process[camera/rgb_rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [2555]
process[camera/rgb_rectify_color-5]: started with pid [2556]
process[camera/ir_rectify_ir-6]: started with pid [2557]
process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7]: started with pid [2559]
process[camera/depth_metric_rect-8]: started with pid [2566]
process[camera/depth_metric-9]: started with pid [2571]
process[camera/depth_points-10]: started with pid [2582]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [2584]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12]: started with pid [2593]
process[camera/depth_registered_sw_metric_rect-13]: started with pid [2601]
process[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-14]: started with pid [2607]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15]: started with pid [2609]
process[camera/depth_registered_hw_metric_rect-16]: started with pid [2614]
process[camera/depth_registered_metric-17]: started with pid [2627]
process[camera/disparity_depth-18]: started with pid [2633]
process[camera/disparity_registered_sw-19]: started with pid [2641]
process[camera/disparity_registered_hw-20]: started with pid [2647]
process[camera_base_link-21]: started with pid [2656]
process[camera_base_link1-22]: started with pid [2663]
process[camera_base_link2-23]: started with pid [2671]
process[camera_base_link3-24]: started with pid [2685]
[ INFO] [1489069886.062036025]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
[ INFO] [1489069890.814802217]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069893.818189792]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069896.820127706]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069899.830134255]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069902.831852753]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069905.834030500]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069908.837267326]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069911.837684329]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069914.839434410]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069917.849733792]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069920.868615640]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069923.870096806]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069926.872154219]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069929.873228220]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069932.874316471]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069935.875022473]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1489069938.875431810]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
10 keep alives is too much - stopping
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  unsigned int openni_wrapper::OpenNIDriver::updateDeviceList() @ /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-openni-camera-1.9.5/src/openni_driver.cpp @ 125 : enumerating image nodes failed. Reason: One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.41: Failed to send a USB control request!

[FATAL] [1489069942.960801346]: Failed to load nodelet '/camera/ir_rectify_ir` of type `image_proc/rectify` to manager `camera_nodelet_manager'
[FATAL] [1489069942.960832929]: Failed to load nodelet '/camera/driver` of type `openni_camera/driver` to manager `camera_nodelet_manager'
[FATAL] [1489069942.965775243]: Failed to load nodelet '/camera/depth_rectify_depth` of type `image_proc/rectify` to manager `camera_nodelet_manager'
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 2552, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/0ad21ed8-04d5-11e7-ad7f-00044b491267/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/0ad21ed8-04d5-11e7-ad7f-00044b491267/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1*.log
[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7] process has died [pid 2559, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=depth/image_raw image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw __name:=depth_rectify_depth __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/0ad21ed8-04d5-11e7-ad7f-00044b491267/camera-depth_rectify_depth-7.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/0ad21ed8-04d5-11e7-ad7f-00044b491267/camera-depth_rectify_depth-7*.log
[camera/driver-2] process has died [pid 2553, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load openni_camera/driver camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond ir:=ir rgb:=rgb depth:=depth depth_registered:=depth_registered projector:=projector __name:=driver __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/0ad21ed8-04d5-11e7-ad7f-00044b491267/camera-driver-2.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/0ad21ed8-04d5-11e7-ad7f-00044b491267/camera-driver-2*.log
[camera/ir_rectify_ir-6] process has died [pid 2557, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=ir/image_raw image_rect:=ir/image_rect_ir __name:=ir_rectify_ir __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/0ad21ed8-04d5-11e7-ad7f-00044b491267/camera-ir_rectify_ir-6.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/0ad21ed8-04d5-11e7-ad7f-00044b491267/camera-ir_rectify_ir-6*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256592/roslaunch-openni_launch-openni.launch-error-with-ros-indigo-version-and-ubuntu-14.04.5-lts-on-jetson-tk1-board/) by [dineth](https://answers.ros.org/users/29263/dineth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
:
(x about 10 times)
```

Make sure you plugged your sensor before running `roslaunch` command.
If your sensor is plugged in for sure, check if OS recognizes it. E.g. on Ubuntu some things to consider:

- Use `lsusb` command.
- Also check if OS emits errors in `/var/log/syslog`

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0